# Sharepoint sites redirecting to wrong address

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

[image]

I am new to sharepoint.so bear with me.i am using sharepoint 2013.my webapplication url is http://192.168.1.6:1506/ . whenever i click sites as marked in image . it redirects me to wrong adress 192.168.1.6//my/personal/administrator/Social/Sites.aspx which is sharepoint80 defaut site .how can i solve this issue . before there was same problem with Aboute me page but i managed to resolve that issue by adding new site collection with template of my site and also by configuring user profile service application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may occur unwanted redirect you to "my site"  page. That you put there with your hands as your top site collection.

First of all You delete this Web app or delete only site collection (that added with **my site** template) and recreate it with **team site** template.

Central admin >> manage Web application >> find your last created site collection and delete it. (those site that create with my site template)

Your problem will be solved don't worry.

Next step after your problem solved You make sure that you start  configuration wizard.

Configuration wizard add your first Web application and site collection. And create for starters users all the thing they need.

Second Try Googling about different site templates and their functions

Searching more about my site and scenarios that **my site** template use for top site collection

you can train more about Stop or delete some services safety if empty site collection.

Train to Delete profile service application from central admin and reconfigure and recreate later. Very easy and no risk of your users not work with their "my sites" try:

Central admin >> server farm setting >> (Google it)

Train more about stop services in sharepoint CA (central admin page) in farm services

Stop profile service in farm services

Train more with *iis* temporary stop Web app for port 80.

Train more about sharepoint topology

Testing scenarios with another admin user and non admin and their permission level and test it. Create new user with active directory users and groups mmc console.